# Filtering DataFrame for specific value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an numpy array `m= pd.unique(ledger_df['Account'])` which is smaller(about 2) in size than a dataframe `x = map.drop_duplicates().sort_index()` (about 13000).

I want to check if the values in m are in x. If so then select the row that matches.

```
x.where(x.ACCT.isin(all(m)==True)['Description']
```

Actual results:

```
10000000    NaN
10000100    NaN
```

Expected:

```
 10000000    Checking
```

Answer (score 1):

To select select those rows of `x` whose ACCT values are in `m` the syntax is:

```
x[x.ACCT.isin(m)]
```

Comment: Thanks, but, that produces a bool table. I want just the value in searched for show up in  x

Comment: Thanks Andy. x[x.ACCT.isin(m)==True] works as expected.

Comment: @DonCheeto please accept this answer if it works for you https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235